# Wordpress add_rewriter_rule results in 301 redirect

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

So I am adding rewrite rules to our Wordpress website, via a plugin that uses

`$target = 'index.php?' . $this->post_type . '=' . $title;
$mapping = $title . '/?$';
add_rewrite_rule ($mapping, $target, 'top');`

That works fine, I can see the rewrite rules in wordpress.
However, when I go to the URL, for example www.foo.com/my-new-page I am getting a 301 redirect back to www.foo.com/.

I am trying to find out where this 301 is triggered. I have flushed the rules after adding my pages, the custom post type is registered, but something is not happy.
The good news is I do not get a 404. If I for example go to `my-new-page2` which doesn't exist, I am immediately served with a 404.

I am using a Jupiter based theme, but I also tried it with the standard Wordpress 2017 theme. Still same issue. There are also no plugins active that are in any way related to this (I think).

Does anyone have a suggestion on where to search?

Comment: _"The good news is I do not get a 404"_ - that might only mean that the mapping part works, but not the target though. Are you sure passing the post type as _parameter name_ is the right way to pass this to the index.php? According to https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars, I would assume that you need to pass _two_ parameters, the post type as `post_type` and the post title as `name`

Comment: Good question. I used this method before where I registered a post_type called `apptizer` and then I registered rules like `([^\/]+)?\/?auth -> index.php?apptizer=auth`. This would allow me to go to `/auth` and it would load a specific template for the apptizer post_type which would bootstrap a single page application for login. This works like a charm. So I was trying the same now, with registering `prospa_job` post_type and registering job_urls like `account-manager/?$ -> index.php?prospa_job=account-manager`. I will have a look what happens if I add post_type in the URL.

Comment: Just tried `index.php?post_type=prospa_job&name=account-manager` and it still triggers a 301. I also see URL rewrite rules like `employees_category/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$ index.php?employees_category=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]` so what I was initially doing is working. Just have to find the reason for the 301.

Comment: One more weird thing is that when I put a die() in Wordpress index.php, it still does a 301 on the url account-manager but not on foo or test. Rebooting apache resolves this. It remembers the 301 apparently.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I figured out what the problem was. I registered the custom_post type in my constructor call, which was to early.

By adding a wp_loaded hook into the constructor, it executed on the right moment, not causing a 301 redirect.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {
  $this->register_post_types( $this->post_type, true, $this->post_label );

} );
```

So just to confirm, it is fine to register the rewrite rule as

```
$target = 'index.php?' . $this->post_type . '=' . $title;
$mapping = '^' . $title . '/?$';
add_rewrite_rule ($mapping, $target, 'top');
```